# How to create a .exe of a python script

Tags: python

I've been trying to use pyinstaller, but it never creates it. There is always this error:
[image: error]

I've found that if I put this, it should work, but it doesn't. Does somebody know how to do it?
.\pyinstaller --onefile -w 'filename.py'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for 'Edit system environment variables' in control panel and add (C:\Users"Your username"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts) to PATH

Answer (score 0):

Add Your pyinstaller directory PATH  to environment variable.